# MenuStrip sub items opening direction

Tags: c#, menustrip

Like I said in the title; I want to change the direction of the sub menu that opens when you click on a menu item.

This image shows the left lower corner of my application. What I want to do is open the menu to the top and not to the bottom as shown.

http://postimg.org/image/8f8zst981/

NOTE: The menustrip is not docked.

Comment: Have you tried docking it? Is there any particular reason why it's not docked?

Comment: The reason was to keep it a certain size, if you dock it, it automatically takes up the whole width. I don't know why I didn't think of it but I docked it to the bottom of a panel of the same size and that work. Thanks for the comment, when I read it, it clicked!

Comment: No problem. If docking is what worked, it's a good idea to post your own answer saying how you solved your problem, then mark it as the correct answer - this will help others facing the same question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I docked it to the bottom of a panel of the same size and that work. With it docked in a panel I still have control over the width by changing the panel width.